# Suppress output in Python calls to executables

Tags: python, redirect

I have a binary named `A` that generates output when called. If I call it from a Bash shell, most of the output is suppressed by `A > /dev/null`. All of the output is suppressed by `A &> /dev/null`

I have a python script named `B` that needs to call `A`. I want to be able to generate output from `B`, while suppressing all the output from `A`.

From within `B`, I've tried `os.system('A')`, `os.system('A > /dev/null')`, and `os.system('A &> /dev/null')`, `os.execvp('...')`, etc. but none of those suppress all the output from A.

I could run `B &> /dev/null`, but that suppresses all of `B`'s output too and I don't want that.

Anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you have Python 2.4, you can use [the subprocess module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html):

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> s = subprocess.Popen(['cowsay', 'hello'], \
      stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0]
>>> print s
 _______ 
< hello >
 ------- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: This will perform poorly if the output to stdout is unbounded.

Comment: cowsay has been around since 1999 and I've never heard of it??

Comment: I've only heard of such a program today

Answer (score 102):

```
import os
import subprocess

command = ["executable", "argument_1", "argument_2"]

with open(os.devnull, "w") as fnull:
    result = subprocess.call(command, stdout = fnull, stderr = fnull)
```

If the command doesn't have any arguments, you can just provide it as a simple string.

If your command relies on shell features like wildcards, pipes, or environment variables, you'll need to provide the whole command as a string, and also specify `shell = True`.  This should be avoided, though, since it represents a security hazard if the contents of the string aren't carefully validated.

Comment: Because the original question used os.system and, not knowing exactly what he's doing, shell = True is the most reliable translation for that.

Comment: DNS, I tried your solution and it works perfectly for me. Thanks!

Comment: So? Tons of people use os.system() without realizing that they need not go through the shell. And now, since you didn't offer the more secure alternative, he's using shell=True, possibly without any good reason whatsoever.

Comment: -1 This also leaks the file handle if `subprocess.call` throws an error. And you should really use `subprocess.DEVNULL` if it's available.

Comment: @phihag Again, I was trying to answer the question as it was asked, with a minimum of extraneous code, in a way that worked in most versions of the language at the time. But, given the answer's popularity, you're right that I shouldn't be giving new visitors the wrong ideas, and so I've edited it to reflect better practices.  I'm not, however, going to confuse people with something that was only introduced in Python 3.3, and is functionally equivalent to what I have above, anyway; that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 21):

In Python 3.3 and higher, `subprocess` supports [an option for redirecting to `/dev/null`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.DEVNULL). To use it, when calling `.Popen` and friends, specify `stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL,` as keyword arguments.

So DNS's answer, rewritten for Python 3.3+, becomes

```
import subprocess
command = ["executable", "argument_1", "argument_2"]
result = subprocess.call(command,
                         stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
                         stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

From the documentation:

> subprocess.DEVNULL¶
>
> Special value that can be used as the stdin, stdout or stderr
>   argument to Popen and indicates that the special file os.devnull will
>   be used.
>
> New in version 3.3.

For Python 3.0 to 3.2, you have to manually open the null device using `open(os.devnull)`, as DNS wrote.

Comment: Unfortunately, `subprocess.DEVNULL` is only available in 3.3+. This answer should be amended with compatibility code (or a reference to it). There is also no reason to use `shell=True`.

Comment: @phihag: I didn't include the compatibility code because DNS's answer adequately describes how to do it without `subprocess.DEVNULL`. You're right about `shell`; fixed.

Answer (score 12):

If your search engine lead you to this old question (like me), be aware that using PIPE may lead to **deadlocks**.
Indeed, because pipes are buffered, you can write a certain number of bytes in a pipe, even if no one read it. However the size of buffer is finite. And consequently if your program A has an output larger than the buffer, A will be blocked on writing, while the calling program B awaits the termination of A. **But not, in this particular case... see comments below.**

Still, I recommend using Devin Jeanpierre and DNS' solution.

Comment: Is this really true? I think it only deadlocks if you use call() or popen()/wait(), but not popen()/communicate().

Comment: Yes! To quote the doc, "Note The data read is buffered in memory, so do not use this method if the data size is large or unlimited."

Comment: "buffered in memory" doesn't necessarily mean that the pipe is deadlocked. The issue they refer to in the docs is that if a command produces a lot of output, it all gets stored in memory on python's heap. This is of course undesirable, and might cause out of memory errors or perform very badly, but only in extreme cases and you won't experience deadlocks.

Comment: First, we shall agree that you do not need to use communicate if you are not interrested in the actual outputs of the program and that in this case using devnull is a much better choice. Second, it appears you are perfectly right: communicate does it job with care and does not deadlock.

Answer (score 8):

As the os.system() docs mention, use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module, and, if you like, set stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w') (and perhaps the same for stderr) when you open the subprocess.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's late to the game, but why not simply redirect output to /dev/null from within os.system?  E.g.:

```
tgt_file = "./bogus.txt"
os.sytem("d2u '%s' &> /dev/null" % tgt_file)
```

This seems to work for those occasions when you don't want to deal with subprocess.STDOUT.

Comment: Because using os.system for system calls is deprecated. The subprocess modules handle that in a much more elegant and secure way

Answer (score 0):

I use:

```
call(command, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

where command is the string of the command + arguments

For this to work you must import subprocess

Answer (score 0):

If you need to just capture STDOUT, doesn't assigning it to a variable do this?  For example:

```
megabyte=''
# Create a 1 MiB string of NULL characters.
for i in range(1048576):
    megabyte += '\0'
fh=open('zero.bin','w')
# Write an 8 GiB file.
for i in range(8192):
    print(i)
    # Suppress output of 'write()' by assigning to a variable.
    discard=fh.write(megabyte)
fh.close()
```

I was creating a large zero-filled file to zero free space on my hard drive and discovered that each call to handle.write(string) spit out the number of bytes written.  Assigning it to a vairable suppressed that output.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to wait for the command to complete, such as starting a backup task, another option is to pass it through bash, doing which allows the redirect to operate normally.

For example, starting a sound file using aplay:

```
import os

def PlaySound(filename):
    command = 'bash -c "aplay %s &> /dev/null &"' % (filename)
    os.system(command)
```

This way I can spawn a new process, not wait for it to finish and stop it from printing to the terminal.
The only catch is that it will load a bash instance as well as the process you are running, providing a slight overhead.