# Simple. *call* function in python. How to fix the return?

Tags: python, function, return, call

See this simple code:

```
$ python
>>> from subprocess import *  
>>> call(['echo','Hi'])
Hi
0
```

My problem looks simple. I don't want this **0** at the end of the call.
Every function called by **call** appears with this and this messes up things for conditional tests.

Something like:

```
if int(call(['function', 'parameter']))>10:
    print 'yes'
```

So how can I receive only

```
Hi
```

in this example?

Comment: You would only see the `0` in the REPL (`echo 'Hi'` returns `0` to indicate success), but you can suppress stdout from `subprocess.call` by assigning it or suppressing if you really want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699325/suppress-output-in-python-calls-to-executables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use Popen with `communicate`, as described in the docs:

```
>>> from subprocess import *
>>> Popen(['echo', 'Hi'], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
'Hi\n'
```

Answer (score 2):

The value you are seeing is the return value of the `echo` process. Because you are in a active interpreter this return value gets printed to the terminal. You can ignore it by assigning it to a dummy variable:

```
_ = call(['echo','Hi'])
```

---

Just making sure, you do know you can just write `print("Hi")`, right?

Comment: Yes this works^^. Almost. How can I set a variable with the result? `>>>a=_=call(['echo','Hi'])` gives `>>>a` `0` and I want `>>>a` `Hi`.

Comment: yes (`print 'Hi'`), but I need this callback from a function of mine, which has a specific return to use in a conditional test.