# Python: How to manage other programs?

Tags: python, user-interface, process

Is there a module that allows me to manage other programs using python (for example to check the position of the cursor on the screen and move it to the other place)? If it does exist please give me it's name I will find out more about it from its doc string. Thank you for your answers :P

Comment: Which OS? That's nothing which can be done in a portable way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controlling the cursor in Python is OS-specific.  In Windows, you need to use the win32api library and in Linux you must use Xlib.  There is a cross platform library called [PyMouse](https://github.com/pepijndevos/PyMouse/) that you might want to check out.

Answer (score 2):

your best bet is probably subprocess, but it depends on the capabilities of these "other programs"

http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Probably you want this: [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html).

---

Anyway, if you need call any function, this clue holds.

To call another program in python you can do:

> `>>>`from subprocess import *
>
> `>>>`call([command, parameter])

Example:

> `>>>`from subprocess import *
>
> `>>>`call(["echo", "Hi"])
>   .

So if you want a return of some function, like the mouse postion, you can call it from python.

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10290157/simple-call-function-in-python-how-to-fix-the-return).

Comment: If in linux,`xautomation` can helps.