# I want to have permission to write to a new file in a subdirectory in python, without using sudo

Tags: python, permissions

It's easy to find people asking how to do this, but there is never an answer that applies to me from what I can tell. I simply want to create permissions, in generality, to write to new files in a subdirectory. Within python I call

```
filename = 'dfs_err_results/err_results_st'+str(station_id)
file = open(filename,'w')
pickle.dump(results, file)
file.close()
```

but it fails at `open()` with `IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'dfs_err_results/err_results_st5'`. If I enter with `sudo python`, that error doesn't occur, but it's annoying to have to remember that and to have to check progress within `sudo ps x` where there are a ton of processes.

Am I correct there's no way to alter the subdirectory for *future* files using chmod? Or no way to have lines of code within the python script that set the permissions?

Thanks!

Comment: There was a similar topic, take a look if it helps 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191878/change-to-sudo-user-within-a-python-script

Comment: I'm sorry can you expand on that? I'm trying to use this `import subprocess` / `subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/sudo", "/usr/bin/id"])` function but I don't think I'm understanding it. This is sending it to execute shell commands under sudo right? And then return to my python function as a normal user? But how do I do this file opening in python within that command? Do I need to make another whole file that I'm sending arguments to?

Comment: This isn't really a Python question but rather a Linux question. You should ask on ServerFault or SuperUser. Of course, if there was a way to get elevated privileges without authentication, that would be a big flaw. You should first design your access rights, then there are a lot of solutions to implement what you need. The `os` module in python provides functions to set permissions on files (but of course only the ones your can access).

Comment: I think it's a Python question, too, given that the answer lies within the subprocess module.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it does execute command with sudo. 
For exmaple, before openning the file you can change its write permission. Do whatever you need and change permission back.
I don't have linux by hand at this moment, by try something like this:

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', 'chmod', '777', filename])
with open(filename) as file:
    pickle.dump(results, file)
```

Comment: I think this only works if the file already exists, but I want it to be able to create a new one the way file.open(name,'w') usually does. And having it use a text editor like vim to do so breaks the python script. Is there a way to create a file without adding any content?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly contributed by xmp but it does require one more line to create the file:

```
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', 'touch', filename])
subprocess.call(['/usr/bin/sudo', 'chmod', '777', filename])
file = open(filename,'w')
pickle.dump(results, file)
file.close()
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Now if only I could suppress the output '0's that come along with it in Python 2.7. [These](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/699325/suppress-output-in-python-calls-to-executables) suggestions aren't compatible and browsing other Popen suggestions hasn't worked so far.

Answer (score 0):

That's what worked for me:

```
os.chmod(filename, stat.S_IRWXO | stat.S_IRWXG | stat.S_IRWXU)
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
     pickle.dump(i, f)
```

this gives full permissions for everything you can choose the permissions you want by changing the stat mode: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_chmod.htm